# Matlab - Replace successive pixel with pixel from the left

Tags: matlab

So, I've quantized a grayscale image with four quantized values. I'm trying to maintain the first pixel of each row of the quantized image and replace each successive pixel with the difference from the pixel to its left.

How would you code this in matlab and can someone explain this to me conceptually?

Also, my concern is that because the image is relatively uniform because of the quantization of the dynamic range, most of the image would appear black, no? It seems to me that only the transition areas and the edges will have some difference in quantized values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the difference to the pixel on the left, all you have to do is subtract the pixels in columns 1,2,3... from the columns 2,3,4...

```
%# create a random image with four values
randomImage = randi(4,[100,90]); %# use different numbers of rows and cols so we know which is which

%# catenate the first column of the image with the difference from the pixel to the left
%# for all pairs of columns in the image
differenceImage = [randomImage(:,1),randomImage(:,1:end-1)-randomImage(:,2:end)];
```

Yes, you'd expect quite a few uniform patches (which will be gray, since unless you plot the absolute value of the differences, there will be some that are negative).

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not quite sure I understand the coding aspect. Mainly because I always forget the right syntax. Can you explain please?

Comment: Hi, it works nonetheless... I think I just need a bit more elaboration on how it works. Thank you.

Comment: @user730255: `[A,B]` appends `B` to the right of `A`. `A(:,1)` is the first column of `A` (i.e. all rows, first column). `A(:,2:end)` is `A` without the first column (i.e. all rows, columns 2 to however many there are). To calculate, for each column (except #1) the difference to the pixels in the column to the left, I make two sub-arrays - one that contains all but the first column, and one that contains all but the last. If I were to overlay these, I'd get, for each pixel in the first sub-array its neighbor to the left in the second sub-array. Then all I do is take the difference.

Comment: @user730255: To better understand this, I suggest that you create the array `randomImage` as `randomImage = magic(4)`, and that you then evaluate the code step by step, i.e. check what `randomImage(:,1:end-1)` results in, etc.

Comment: @Jonas: You could simplify your code with `[randomImage(:,1) -diff(randomImage,1,2)]`.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks. That was actually my first solution. However, I wanted to keep it simpler by explicitly stating the difference since @user730255 wanted to try and understand how it works.